# How to join line?

Tags: html, canvas, line

I need to draw a curve/shape that will change its width during the time. So I need to draw each line at time, changing width for each chunk. But doing this, it introduces a gap between the lines.

Here an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/w6nu0tgy/6/) with a single beginPath/stroke (lines are automatically joined):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath
ctx.strokeStyle='#cc0000';
ctx.lineWidth=10;
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(100,60);
ctx.stroke();
```

and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w6nu0tgy/7/) instead a beginPath/stroke for each part of the shape (where I could change width for each line, once I fix this problem):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath;
ctx.strokeStyle='#cc0000';
ctx.lineWidth=10;
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(50,50);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath;
ctx.strokeStyle='#cc0000';
ctx.lineWidth=10;
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(100,60);
ctx.stroke();
```

As you can see in the last example, there's a gap between the two lines.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Why can't you move to other point like this: https://jsfiddle.net/w6nu0tgy/8/. It's not generic but it does the work.

Comment: ctx.moveTo(48,49); in place of 50,50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the way caps are rendered:

```
ctx.lineCap = "round";
```

This will extend the line segment with "half" a circle which allows for a more smooth overlapping.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/tyLr27m9/)**

Comment: You makes my day! Thank you very much!

Comment: For what I need (just lines joined) it's perfect ;)

Comment: @MoshFeu you could always treat first and last segment separately by f.ex. interpolating the length 50%, draw the inner parts with round caps, the outer parts without.